# Responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers - HTTP Status 406 - spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

> **Any takers to resolve this issue for USD50, please contact**

I am getting the not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers, however, I believe I have done everything right, I could. Can someone help to resolve this issue. I am using Spring 4.1.

The **OBJECTIVE** is to be able to return the response in the **text/xml** format. if I remove produces=text/xml directive then my application works i.e. no error, but the source system treat the response in an unexpected way.

Request coming in as follows:
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 78637a4f-e153-4242-c922-96757d01442a" -d Then values....

**My Pom:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0.rc1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0.rc1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

**My Controller have the following notations:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@EnableWebMvcMy Controller has the following notations:
```

**Main Class has the following notation**
    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @ComponentScan

I DO NOT have the application context xml, as i am using @Autowired
on my end-point method as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/IDEA",  headers = {"Accept=*/*"}, produces="text/xml",    method= {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
@Autowired
public MyResult processMyRequest(HttpServletRequest request)
```

**Current Log**

2016-08-11 13:38:04.076  INFO 89535 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.f.fnocc.injestor.MyController    :  POST CALLED
2016-08-11 13:38:04.079  INFO 89535 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.f.fnocc.injestor.MyController    : Request received from ipAddress:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
2016-08-11 13:38:04.082  INFO 89535 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.f.fnocc.injestor.MyController    : REQUEST INFORMATION: [
2016-08-11 13:38:04.084  INFO 89535 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@af3b571: startup date [Thu Aug 11 13:38:04 BST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-11 13:38:04.095  INFO 89535 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-08-11 13:38:04.119  INFO 89535 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@142abfa2: startup date [Thu Aug 11 13:38:04 BST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-11 13:38:04.124  INFO 89535 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-08-11 13:38:04.150 ERROR 89535 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.f.fnocc.injestor.MyController    : Error has occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue I see is `@EnableWebMvc` should be specified on the main class alongside the `@Configuration` but I don't think it is even needed when you are specifying `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

The other issue is the `@RequestMapping()` has an attribute for [`consumes`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#consumes--) which is what you should probably be using instead of looking for the accept header. Reason for that is the accept header normally includes multiple media types not just `*/*` as such the check for equality on that header wouldn't be there.

*** Update *** I was wrong on the `consumes` that is used to interpreting the `Content-Type` header and not the `Accept` header. Spring tries to match the `produces` to the `Accept` header to determine if the method can respond to the incoming request. That makes more sense why you are getting the 406 error as Spring sees the method trying to output `text/xml` but the request probably doesn't accept that content type in the `Accept` header.

To further troubleshoot you can setup a request logger to see the specifics on how the request is coming into the service to determine if there is something that is causing Spring to not process it properly. If you add the following bean and enable DEBUG level logging on `org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`then you can see.

```
@Bean
public Filter logFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    filter.setIncludeQueryString(false);
    filter.setIncludePayload(false);
    filter.setIncludeHeaders(true);
    return filter;
}
```

If you can update your question with that request log that would help to troubleshoot.

*** Update #2 *** Was able to reproduce the error. Adding `DEBUG` logging level for `org.springframework.web` showed the issue more clearly.

```
2016-08-11 02:26:58.242 DEBUG 82904 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/test/IDEA]
2016-08-11 02:26:58.244 DEBUG 82904 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /test/IDEA
2016-08-11 02:26:58.247 DEBUG 82904 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public ca.tuatara.stackoverflow.MyController$MyResult ca.tuatara.stackoverflow.MyController.processMyRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2016-08-11 02:26:58.247 DEBUG 82904 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/test/IDEA] is: -1
2016-08-11 02:26:58.258 DEBUG 82904 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public ca.tuatara.stackoverflow.MyController$MyResult ca.tuatara.stackoverflow.MyController.processMyRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

The `Could not find acceptable representation` is the key. By specifying that you want XML you must include a library to marshall the object as XML as described on the [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-write-an-xml-rest-service) docs. Adding the dependency for:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Made it work for my sample application. Give that a try!

Comment: Hi Shawn, I really appreciate your response. I start getting the 406 error after introducing produces="text/xml" in the @RequestMapping I need it as the source system requires the response in the text/xml format. So if anyone can help me to force the response in text/xml it will be fantastic.

Comment: Request:
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 78637a4f-e153-4242-c922-96757d01442a" -d Then values....

Response:                                                                                                   The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.52</h3></body></html>

Comment: Add a `-H "Accept: text/xml"` to the curl call. Sorry for not catching the example curl call in the original question. Would have made this a bit easier.

Comment: Shawn, it is still the same, I really appreciate your time and effort.
Request:
curl -X POST -H "Accept: text/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 78637a4f-e153-4242-c922-96757d01442a" 

Response:
HTTP Status 406 - Status report message, description The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

Comment: Sorry Shawn, no luck after adding the dependency, I am trying to switch on the debug unsuccessfully at the minute, I have attached the current log in the main update. thanks so much once more.

Comment: Going to try and make a sample project... just want to confirm if you are using any Spring Boot within your application or if it is specifically just Spring 4.1 with dependencies?

Comment: Hey thanks Shawn, sorry it is 4.0 see below - <project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

Comment: I can make it easy for you Shawn we can have a 5-10 minute session where you can see my project - I am sure for some seasoned in spring-boot like yourself it will take 5 minutes. Many thanks again to respond again.

Comment: Thank you, Shawn, for resolving the issue. Basically updating the org.springframework.boot to 1.4.0 and general tidying up resolved the issue.